# I am trying to simulate a mass, on a friction less floor, with a spring, fixed at one end. Not working

Tags: python, spring, matplotlib, scipy

I am using the standard differential equation for SHM for the above simulation, a = -w^2*x. I'm using Python with the odeint being the solver. Despite editing it several times, I keep getting the output as a straight line instead of a sinusoidal curve. The code is:

```
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from pylab import *

k = 80 #Spring Constant
m = 8  #mass of block
omega = sqrt(k/m) #angular velocity

def deriv(x,t):
    return array([x[1],(-1)*(k/m)*x[0]])

t = linspace(0,3.62,100)

xinit = array([0,0])

x = odeint(deriv,xinit,t)

acc_mass = zeros(t.shape[0])

for q in range(0,t.shape[0]):
    acc_mass[q] = (-1)*(omega**2)*x[q][0]

f, springer = subplots(3, sharex = True)
springer[0].plot(t,x[:,0],'r')
springer[0].set_title('Position Variation')
springer[1].plot(t,x[:,1],'b')
springer[1].set_title('Velocity Variation')
springer[2].plot(t,acc_mass,'g')
springer[2].set_title('Acceleration Variation')
```

Comment: Sounds like a Maths problem

Comment: Yes, but the differential equation is correct. I don't whether the implementation is!

Comment: The differential equation is linear and homogenous, and you have given the initial conditions (0, 0).  The solution for those initial conditions is identically 0.  That is, it is working!  Try changing the initial conditions, e.g. `xinit = array([1.0, 0])`.

Comment: Perfect! I corrected it and got the proper output. It is a rather elementary mistake. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by Warren Weckesser, the code is correct, but since the initial conditions are given as 0  for the displacement, the output is also 0. Hence on his advice, I changed the initial conditions and got the required output which was a sinusoidal curve.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete example of SHM using `odeint`:

http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/dpsanders/d417c1ffbb76f13f678c#2D-equations